# active record where {}

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I can not find any reference how this works:

```
Order.where {(expirate_at >= 10.days.ago) & (expirate_at <= 9.days.ago)}
```

which gives sql query:

```
SELECT `orders`.* FROM `orders` 
  WHERE ((`orders`.`expirate_at` >= '2013-03-10 09:22:23' 
    AND `orders`.`expirate_at` <= '2013-03-11 09:22:23'))
```

Can someone explain it, please?

**update:**

```
Order.where({(expirate_at >= 10.days.ago) & (expirate_at <= 9.days.ago)})
```

ends with

```
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC
... & (expirate_at <= 9.days.ago)})
```

Comment: It works the ruby way - http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: I know how where() works but never found example why it works with {}. There is no reference to this in tutorials. I was searching for explanation before I wrote a question, but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was [squeel](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/squeel) gem used in that project.
Mystery resolved. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is what the ruby way.

```
Order.where {}
```

is nothing but

```
Order.where({})
```

Comment: It is not true. Order.where({(expirate_at >= 10.days.ago) & (expirate_at <= 9.days.ago)})
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting tASSOC
... & (expirate_at <= 9.days.ago)})